# Initializing a nested member with properties unknown in advance

Tags: c#, oop, initialization

There is an abstract class `Subject` which has 2 derived classes: `Company` and `Person`. Both have shared members like `name` or `address` as well as not shared properties unique to each. Let's say the `Company` has a property `int employeesNumber`, while person has a property `string insuranceID`. Now, since both `Company` and `Person` are supposed to work in the same pipeline (being stored in lists, seinding data to userforms etc), those "odd" properties are the cause of my problems. Here's what I tried to do:

first I make a base abstract class `Subject` which has the shared `name` and `address` properties as well as an interface `IOtherProps` for the odd properties. Even though the classes, implementing the interface share no properties by design, and therefore the interface is a blank, I used it so only few classes could be valid to implement it.

```
public abstract class subject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    public IOtherProps otherprops;
}

public interface IOtherProps
{

}
```

Next, we have `Company` and `Person` derived classes, each implementing `PropsCompany` and `PropsPerson` classses respectively through `IOtherProps` to  store the class specific data:

```
public class Company : Subject
{
    public Company()
    {
        otherprops = new PropsCompany();
    }
}
public class Person : Subject
{
    public Person()
    {
        otherprops = new PropsPerson();
    }
}

public class PropsCompany : IOtherProps
{
    public int employeesNumber { get; set; }
}
public class PropsPerson : IOtherProps
{
    public string insuranceID { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's try to initialize an object:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person()
        {
            name = "John Smith", //ok
            otherprops = { insuranceID = "12345" } // CS0117 C# \
//"IOtherProps" doesn't contain definition for "insuranceID".
        };
    }
```

C# won't let me initialize a nested class that only get initialized in the `Person()` constructor. The linter won't even give me a prompt on the members of `otherprops` and I might not remember which class contains which odd properties.

So I tried to override the `otherprops` in the `Person` class, got another error:

```
public class Person : Subject
{
    public Person()
    {

    }
    public override PropsPerson otherprops = new PropsPerson();// CS0106 C# The modifier 
    //'modifier' is not valid for this item
}
```

So, my question is: how do I initialize `insuranceId` in this example? And more general question: is my solution of handling the "odd" data like that is generally correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You may use `otherprops = new PropsPerson { insuranceID = "12345" }` instead of `otherprops = { insuranceID = "12345" }` to get rid of an error (since `IOtherProps` doesn't contain any members you should tell which concrete class is used to init this field). Also, there is a typo `subject->Subject`

Answer (score 0):

`otherProps` is defined on the `subject` base class as `IOtherProps`, which does not contain `insuranceID`.

Furthermore, you cannot override a field. If it was a property you could declare it `virtual` to solve CS0117, but you cannot override a property with a different type.

You need to declare `subject` as a generic type, and declare the field/property as that type:

```
public abstract class subject<TOtherProps> where TOtherProps : IOtherProps
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    public TOtherProps otherprops {get; set;} // or you could leave it as a field
}
```

Then Person can be declared like so:

`public class Person : Subject<PropsPerson>`

Now, the type of `otherprops` is statically known to be `PropsPerson`, which also implements `IOtherProps`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a known distinct problem to handle similar objects with "misfitting" members? If so, what should I read about it?

Comment: Generics are pretty standard, the BCL uses generics everywhere. See `List<T>` for example which contains an array of `T`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `IOtherProps` interface, I would just add the other properties unique to the `Person` and `Company` classes directly in those classes.

```
public abstract class Subject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Subject
{
    public Person()
    {
        public string InsuranceID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the more common implementation for multiple concrete implementations of an abstract class and easily allows you to do exactly what you want.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person person = new Person()
    {
        Name = "John Smith",
        InsuranceID = "12345"
    };
}
```

The only thing you lose the supposed protection of only a few classes being able to implement it but I'm not sure how effective that would be anyway.

Comment: I agree, but the reason I wanted to put them in a nested class is becase I think it's not very tidy to "scatter" the odd properties among the properties of an abstract class especially if the class is bigger than the example presented.

Comment: I think I see your point but I guess I just see it differently.  I see all of those properties as really being a part of the concrete classes, not odd properties scattered around; to create a `Person`, you need a `Name` and an `InsuranceID` so they all belong together just like would be if `Person` was not an implementation of `Subject`.  If you want to stick with the existing design, I would definitely recommend the approach that Pavel Anikhouski mentioned in the comment on the question.